# Energy Balls Too Dry

Tags: baking, peanut-butter

I would love some feedback on my energy bites I home back. I have been experimenting with various recipes but continually find they are to dry. I need to make sure I have a cup of water with me whenever I eat them so my throat doesn’t get too dry.

My recipe is
⅔ Cup coconut flour
⅔ cup rice puffs
2 tablespoon ground flaxseed
2 tablespoon honey
2 tablespoon date paste
1 cup natural/organic peanut butter
2 teaspoon vanilla extract

I mix them all in a kitchenaide for about 30 seconds then roll them into small balls. I then bake them at 350 for 14 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The flax seed and dates are acting as binding in this case.

The dryness will be from the coconut flour, I think you can't get around this without adding some moisture somewhere. Oil will make it too loose, so you will probably need water.

I would hydrate the flax seed a little bit in water, perhaps add a teaspoon (~ 5ml) of water and sit for 5 min, adjust as necessary. You could also add some water to the date paste, but how much is difficult to say.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could try not cooking them! You actually don't have to [cook](https://www.theconsciousplantkitchen.com/can-you-eat-raw-flours/) coconut flour (or almond flour). Perhaps adding a little more honey or water to make sure they stick, roll into balls, and put in the fridge for 30 minutes. This would result in a less-dry product.